# Unable to split by NULL byte (\0)

Tags: c++, sockets

I am having an issue with C++ and sockets. I am trying to split (basically, read by) the NULL byte ("\0"), as this is what Flash terminates with. I am also trying to write by this. As far as I can tell, the split is working fine.

My issue is that I'm unable to write PACKET + \0 to the Flash client successfully, and I am confident that the issue is server sided. I'm pretty new to C++ so I'm unable to debug and I've had little help elsewhere (usually due to the people I've asked having no idea), or I was pointed here by those same people. I would appreciate any help on the matter, thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
int intPort = 8080;
int resSocket;
struct sockaddr_in strctAddr;
void log(std::string strText, std::string strType = "INFO"){
        time_t rawtime;
        struct tm * timeinfo;
        char buffer [80];
        time(&rawtime);
        timeinfo = localtime(&rawtime);
        strftime(buffer, 50, "%c",timeinfo);
        std::cout << "[" << buffer << "][" << strType << "] > " << strText << std::endl;
} 
void error(std::string strError){
        log(strError, "SHUTDOWN");
        exit(1);
}
/* initialize() method
 * Starts up server by setting up a socket() and bind()ing to intPort to listen() for clients
*/
int initialize(int intPort){
        std::stringstream objStringStream;
        objStringStream << intPort;
        log("Initializing socket server");
        resSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        if(resSocket < 0) error("Could not create socket.");
        bzero((char *) &strctAddr, sizeof(strctAddr)); //I'm pretty sure this clears strctAddr or something
        strctAddr.sin_family = AF_INET; //sets socket as AF_INET
        strctAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; //sets socket address to "0"
        strctAddr.sin_port = htons(intPort); //sets socket port to the value of intPort
        setsockopt(resSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (struct sockaddr *) &strctAddr, sizeof(strctAddr));
        if(bind(resSocket, (struct sockaddr *) &strctAddr, sizeof(strctAddr)) < 0) //Binds socket
                error("Could not bind");
        listen(resSocket, 5);
        log("Listening for clients on " + objStringStream.str(), "FINE");
        return 1;
}
/* write()'s strData to resSock */
int sendPacket(int resSock, char* strData){
        int intWrite;
        strcat(strData, "\0");
        log("Sending packet: " + std::string(strData), "SEND");
        intWrite = write(resSock, strData, strlen(strData));
        return intWrite;
}
/* handles resSock's data (strData) */
void handleData(int resSock, char* strData){
        char * chData;
        chData = strtok(strData, "\0");
        while(chData != NULL){
                std::string strPacket = chData;
                log("Received data: " + std::string(strPacket), "RECV");
                if(strPacket.compare("<policy-file-request/>") == 0){
                        log("Policy request received");
                        std::string strSend = "<cross-domain-policy><allow-access-from domain='*' to-ports='*'/></cross-domain-policy>";
                        char chSend[6486];
                        strcpy(chSend, strSend.c_str());
                        sendPacket(resSock, chSend);
                }
                chData = strtok(NULL, "\0");
        }
}
/* handles resSock's incoming data and disconnections */
void handleClient(int resSock){
        char chBuffer[6486];
        int intRead;
        while(true){
                bzero(chBuffer, 6486);
                intRead = read(resSock, chBuffer, 6486);
                if(chBuffer == NULL) continue;
                if(intRead <= 0){
                        log("Client disconnected");
                        close(resSock);
                        break;
                } else {
                        handleData(resSock, chBuffer);
                }
        }
}
/* accept()'s incomming connections and spawns a thread for each of them */
void listenToClients(){
        while(true){
                std::stringstream objStringStream;
                struct sockaddr_in clntAddr;
                socklen_t intClients = sizeof(clntAddr);
                int resClient = accept(resSocket, (struct sockaddr *) &clntAddr, &intClients);
                if(resClient < 0) log("Failed to accept client", "ERROR");
                char floatIP[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
                inet_ntop(AF_INET, &clntAddr.sin_addr, floatIP, sizeof floatIP);    
                objStringStream << floatIP;    
                log("New client connected (IP: " + objStringStream.str() + ")");
                std::thread objThread(handleClient, resClient);
                objThread.detach();
        }
}
int main(){
        initialize(intPort);
        listenToClients();
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to. I can't see the problem and neither can anybody else who I'd think to ask. That's why I'm asking here.

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work? What error do you get?

Comment: I attempted to connect with a client (Flash), and it terminated after not receiving the crossdomain policy correctly. I know it doesn't work because Flash is not reconnecting and sending data. (Flash makes two connections, one for the crossdomain, if the crossdomain is valid/allows that domain+port it does the rest, one for the rest of the data/application).

Comment: "learn to debug" does not equal "ask anybody I'd think to ask".  It means using a debugger or log statements or tcpdump or other network sniffer validate that you're sending the correct data, that the correct data is on the wire, and that you're receiving the correct data.  Once you've figured out which of these things is wrong, then you know where to start fixing it.

Comment: In C and C++, '\0' is the string terminator. You can't use any strXXX() functions if your data can contain literal null characters. You have to use functions that operate on raw byte arrays. For instance, `strcat(strData, "\0");` doesn't do anything, and `intWrite = write(resSock, strData, strlen(strData));` doesn't write the null byte (because strlen doesn't include it in the length).

Comment: OK, so what gets logged to the output?

Comment: I sniffed packets and one a fake client I hacked up, the first few characters were missing from the packet. Wireshark did not show the \0 (is it meant to?), so I guess that is my problem.

Comment: It seems to me you are new to C too.

Answer (score 1):

1 Delete the `strcat(strData, "\0");`, which does nothing.

2 Change the write to:

```
write(resSock, strData, strlen(strData)+1);
```

which will include the NUL char that you are seeking.

3 Change the signature of `sendPacket` to `int sendPacket(int resSock, const char* strData)`.

4 Change the invocation of `sendPacket` to

```
std::string strSend = "<cross-domain-policy><allow-access-from domain='*' to-ports='*'/></cross-domain-policy>";
sendPacket(resSock, strSend.c_str());
```

or even simpler:

```
sendPacket(resSock, "<cross-domain-policy><allow-access-from domain='*' to-ports='*'/></cross-domain-policy>");
```

5 Finally, restructure everything to pass `const std::string&` around, and call `c_str()` at the last possible moment. There is almost no room in a well-written C++ program for naked pointers.

Answer (score 0):

The line `strcat(strData, "\0");` doesn't do anything, since `"\0"` is an empty string - a C-style string always stops at the first `\0` no matter how many it contains. You might have better luck appending a single char to a `std::string`.

Answer (score 0):

Complete Rewrite of the Answer

```
std::string strSend = "<cross-domain-policy><allow-access-from domain='*' to-ports='*'/></cross-domain-policy>";
sendPacket(resSock, strSend.c_str());
```

That strcpy over there is useless. Use it like this and modify your sendPacket function to send `strlen(strData)+1` (since .c_str of string already has the `\0` NULL terminator at the end. But strlen only counts **up to** that, not including the null.

However you probably only want this behavior for this header part.